Java WildCard list to Specific JavaList
I am working on a fileReader Utility. I am facing some challenge in type casting.
I have a List as below
Class classType= getClassType("");
List<?> list= reader.read(file,classType);

This is the code I am having, I want to convert the list of ? into type classType
as below
List<classType> list;

I am providing class type at runtime to my reader and it is converting the data into classtype format.

classType is a variable. You can’t write the name of a variable into <…> and there’s no sense in trying. If you weren’t using the raw type Class but used, e.g. Class<ActualType> classType = … you could get a List<ActualType> from the read method when properly designed.

You can define a generic placeholder for the reader.read method:
public <E> List<E> read(File f, Class<E> classType) {
    // your code
}

For example, if read is called with Class<Example>, then the E acts as Example in the method during compile time.
Then, you can update your main code as
Class<Example> classType = (Class<Example>) getClassType("Example");
List<Example> list = reader.read(file, classType);

Here I assume you cannot get the generic type for the class object from its name, which is usually the case (e.g. Class.forName), so I added the generic cast.
Note that it is not recommended to use raw types (e.g. Class alone without <>).
